# Mercurial: get latest head revision of branch from remote repo

Tags: mercurial

I am looking for simple solution for my deployment bash script.

Each run of this script should add tag to the latest revision on `production` branch, but of the remote repo.

People running the script might have own `production` changesets, not pushed to the remote repo, and my server is getting code directly from the remote repo with read-only access. This is why I need to get latest changeset from remote repo, but commit tag locally.

I tried tricks like:

`hg identify -i $(hg paths default)`

- it's great, but gives only tip rev, cannot define branch

`hg heads production`

- it's great again, returns latest branch head, but only from local repo..

Hope there is something else that I'm missing and there is a way to get that remote branch head revision id..

Comment: I use mercurial, but I can't figure out what you are trying to do. Might `hg incoming` be of use?

Comment: Accepted answer is all what I meant: `remote branch head revision id`. Now I have locally my own head revision in this branch but am able to get remote's one.

Comment: @msw That will probably just say `no changes found`, which doesn't help. The asked question is a bit unclear though. (and yes, I know it's an old one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
hg identify --id $(hg paths default)#production
```

That's using the `#revision` specifier, which is described in `hg help urls`.

Answer (score 7):

Through experimentation, I was able to tweak the answer above and make it one process exec rather than two (i.e, it skips `hg paths default`), if that's important to you:

```
hg identify --id --rev production default
```

If you want the local revision for a specific branch (rather than current branch), then use:

```
hg identify --id --rev production
```

Where `production` is the branch you want.